# Jenkins - How to use output of 1st maven command in 2nd maven command?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins to run Maven goals.

Command 1 -

```
mvn test
```

(runs default profile)
(creates a few output folders that are used by Command 2 below)

Command 2 -

```
mvn test -P secondMavenProfileName
```

(second maven profile in pom.xml that needs to process the output files created by Command 1).

How do I run these 2 commands in a single Jenkins job? The requirement is that the output files of Command 1 must be generated by the time Command 2 starts and Command 2 should be able to operate on them.

What is the right way to achieve this in a Jenkins pipeline?

When I simply add the above two commands one-after-the-other in a Jenkins pipeline, the job fails as the 1st command's output files are not generated/written by the time Command 2 starts.

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline script:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    
    stages {
        
        stage('Create file and wait') {
            steps {
                bat 'mvn -help > mvn.txt'
                bat '@ping -n 10 localhost > nul'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Use file') {
            steps {
                bat 'type mvn.txt'
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Console Output excerpt:

```
...
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Create file and wait)
[Pipeline] bat
00:52:23  
00:52:23  C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\SO-68673343 Pipeline stage 1 output used in stage 2>mvn -help  1>mvn.txt 
[Pipeline] bat
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Use file)
[Pipeline] bat
00:52:33  
00:52:33  C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\SO-68673343 Pipeline stage 1 output used in stage 2>type mvn.txt 
00:52:33  
00:52:33  usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
00:52:33  
00:52:33  Options:
00:52:33   -am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
00:52:33                                          build projects required by the
00:52:33                                          list

...        ...                                    ...

00:52:33   -X,--debug                             Produce execution debug output
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```